# Preserving File Timestamp During File Recovery Using Git

Tags: git

You can recover the file using the git command, returning the date and time of the file from the previous version. Without using git-restore-mtime, just the parameters of git itself

I didn't find it using the git parameter itself.

Comment: Which timestamp would you set? Git doesn't track the modification timestamps of files.

Answer (score 1):

Please be reminded that changing timestamps backward is a problem for tools that rely on timestamps such as `make`. For example as a Python programmer I often recompile Python text to byte-code files; sometimes I restore timestamps, but I always first recompile and then restore timestamps.

Please be also advised that Git doesn't store file timestamps, it only stores commit timestamps. So either you store the file timestamps yourself (using some ready-made tools like `git-restore-mtime`, `metastore` or [`mtree`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+mtree), or you implement that yourself), or you restore commit timestamp instead of file timestamps.

As for commit timestamp you can do something like this:

```bash
commit_date="`git show --format='%cD' -s`" &&
touch --date="$commit_date" `git diff --name-only HEAD~`
```

to set committer timestamp for changed (since previous commit) files. Minor modifications of this:

```bash
commit_date="`git show --format='%cD' -s`" &&
touch --date="$commit_date" `git ls-files --cached`
```

set timestamps on all committed files.

```bash
commit_date="`git show --format='%cD' -s`" &&
find . \( -name .git -type d -prune \) -o \
   -exec touch --date="$commit_date" '{}' \+
```

set timestamp on all files in the working tree, committed, ignored, temporary (except the `git/` directories).

The code above only works with the latest commit (`HEAD`). Modification for any commit is trivial. But you still need two programs beyond just `git` — a `sh`-compatible shell like `bash` and `touch`; for the last one also `find`.